# Website not shown in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: web, dns, cloud, platform

I have created a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) account with a domain name from Google Domains, registered with Google. I have created the project, bucket, storage, VM, and uploaded my personal website file(s) and folder(s) to propagate on for viewing. I believe that having followed all of the requested instruction(s) I should be able to view my website. I have also checked for the correct DNS server(s) and resource record(s) for my domain. In all cases when entering the information at the specified locations, I am informed that the information already exists or that there is a conflict error with my entry.

I am hoping that I can find the answers that I need as I have tried several times to contact Google support but to no avail. YouTube video(s) have provided some info but not resolving the issue.

Any assistance would be truly appreciated.

Comment: It will be very hard to help you without knowledge of your domain name.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that it was required. The domain name is ricxcarter.com

Comment: it is not required, but now I can see that there is no `A` record for this domain, so no IP address is associated with ricxcarter.com.

Comment: in going to the DNS records for the domain on the GCP m an IP address was showing but not it has been removed and when I entered the number and the as the A record it would state it was a naming conflict.  It has been two weeks since this has begun and I just want to see my website online.

Comment: i went back to the GCP and found the VM was disabled. I restarted the VM, copied the public IP address, and entered it in the DNS records for Google Domains, as well as the www. record. It states the usual 48-hour window is needed to take place, Thanks for your help.

Comment: I finally the index page to load for my website. My new dilemma that other pages(3) are not showing.  Also, the css files and images are not available but are loaded. I am receiving the following message when attempting to access links from the site: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below: <Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>